# python numpy range() and sum(-1)

Tags: python, numpy

Python question:

```
print(sum(range(5),-1)) 
from numpy import * 
print(sum(range(5),-1))

9
10
```

What is logical behind it? Thank you

Comment: Numpy must be redefining `range`, and it has different boundry rules.

Comment: The first line is equivalent to `0+1+2+3+4+(-1)`. The third line is equivalent to `0+1+2+3+4` on `axis=-1`. Use `import numpy as np` and then rewrite the third line as `np.sum(range(5),-1)`. And read the documentation for [np.sum()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)

Comment: Numpy does not redefine `range`. The second argument in `np.sum()` is `axis`. It will only sum the items in the first argument.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Shot in the dark. I didn't think a summing function could have different behavior.

Answer (score 4):

numpy.sum() signature is as follows (with some arguments omitted):

```
numpy.sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, ...)
```

Python's `sum` signature:

```
sum(iterable, start=0)
```

`sum` iterates over supplied iterable, sums the values, and then adds -1 (i.e. substracts 1).
`numpy.sum` just sums all the values from supplied iterable, and receives an `axis` parameter as `1`, which in your case doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: It's not so important, but `sum` doesn't add the `start` value at the end of the operation - it rather _starts_ with the `start` value which defaults to 0, and adds the sequence to it. Like in CPython [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/57c157be847f/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2293).